# How to ignore a quarkus test

Tags: java, testing, junit, quarkus

I am testing my Quarkus application, and I would like to ignore some of my tests.

The test class is annotated with `@io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest`, and each method with `@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

I'm trying to use the `@org.junit.Ignore` annotation, but it's not working, the ignored tests are executed anyway.

This is the code:

```
@QuarkusTest
@TestHTTPEndpoint(MyResource::class)
class MyResourceTest {

    @Test
    @Ignore
    fun `to be ignored`() {
        assertTrue(false)
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I think you are mixing JUnit4 & JUnit5 annotations. [@Disabled](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Disabled.html) should be used to ignore a test with JUnit5. Also, I would try to exclude the JUnit4 dependencies from the build.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `@Disabled` annotation

You can also conditionally run tests with [assumptions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assumptions.html).

Comment: Note that `@Disabled` is a Junit5 annotation (which works) and not directly related to Quarkus.